# Unable to add text-to-speech in Python IDE Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, text-to-speech

Hello i am trying to add text-to-speech in my python project, however i am unable to find a good solution.

I have tried:

- playsound
- tkinter-tkSnack
- os
- gtts
- ffmpeg
- speech_recgonition

I have tried all the methods above on PyCharm, IDLE and python shell with no results.
Python 3.7 
pip-2.1

I have not seen and results online suggesting its not impossible.

Comment: You haven't explained what your issue is. I've used the `speech_recognition` library before and it's pretty straightforward to use. Are you sure you typed, `pip install speechrecognition` into your Windows/Linux shell?

Comment: What do you mean you tried all the methods. What do you mean no results? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. If you google `Python text to speech` and install the first result what do you get?: [**`pyttsx3`**](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/).

Comment: When I google it, I get [this](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/text-to-speech/) as my first search result. Have you tried any of the modules listed in here?

Comment: @TheMaker OP wants text-to-speech not speech recognition.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try win32com, a python module:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
speak = Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")

speak.Speak('Hello world.')
```